# create-react-app starting error - Error: No valid exports main found for '\node_modules\colorette'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

When installing `create-react-app`, I get this error when I start the development server (npm start):

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: No valid exports main found for 'myproject\node_modules\colorette'
```

I've reinstalled `create-react-app` globally with `create-react-app -g` and tried running it with `npx`, but I still get this error.
Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: So basically (almost) every answer here is saying, "Upgrade to the latest version of node."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed this problem by upgrading node.js to v14.5, i've had v13.5 and v13.6 in my laptop.
and also removing create-react-app globally:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and using:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: I had this problem too since today (using npx create-react-app myapp). Updating node.js to version 14.5 solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Downgrading to 12.18.2 also helps:

in package.json, 
 "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.2"
  }

Comment: I had this problem today, updating the node version worked for me too

Answer (score 9):

Node version 13 has an issue for ReactJs, please check your version.
You can update or degrade(LTS version) your node version to work ReactJs properly

Answer (score 7):

you need to upgrade node version to 14.5 or latest version with:

```
sudo n latest // on mac or linux for latest version
```

for windows just reinstall you node with latest version

Answer (score 6):

Upgrade to version 14.5 will solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using `nvm`,

you can use `nvm install <version-number>` to install any version.

In my case, I had v13.2.0 previously installed.

So, I checked all available versions with `nvm ls-remote`

And then picked the latest version to install like so:

`nvm install v14.8.0`

and as per @iamnabink comment - `nvm use v14.8.0`

Comment: And dont forget to use installed version with command `nvm use v14.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is because latest version of colorette doesn't supported on node Version < 14.
Try below steps if you don't want to install node V14.5

To uninstall colorette:
npm uninstall colorette

To install colorette version 1.2.0:
npm install colorette@1.2.0

This fixed my issue.

Else you can simply upgrade the node version.

Comment: Thanks. On windows 7, where you can't upgrade node, this is the perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem by upgrading node.js to v14.5.0. After upgrading, I also had to delete my node_modules folder and rerun `npm install`.